# liquibase migration failed while dropColumn boolean variable

Tags: boolean, integration-testing, h2, liquibase

I am using Liquibase for chaining Data Base (H2) alterations and recently I faced removal of unnecessary column migration exception:
`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: View "ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.CE_SOME_TABLE DROP COLUMN some_column" is invalid: "Column ""SOME_TABLE .SOME_COLUMN"" not found [42122-190]"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.CE_SOME_TABLE DROP COLUMN some_column[90109-190]`

I have tried the following:

1. To check if my DB really find such column:

`select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='ce_some_table';`

It shows that such column name exists along the other columns in that table

2. Tried to write SQL statement in liquibase:

`<sql>ALTER TABLE ce_some_table DROP COLUMN some_column;</sql>`

Did not do the job

3. Tried to rename variable (thought DB metadata was cashed):

   `<renameColumn catalogName="some_catalog"
                         columnDataType="boolean"
                         newColumnName="some_column2"
                         oldColumnName="some_column"
                         remarks="A Boolean"
                         schemaName="public"
                         tableName="CE_SOME_TABLE"/>`

And then to drop the renewed column:

```
<dropColumn tableName="CE_SOME_TABLE" columnName="some_column2"/>
```

Also have not worked

4. Have tried to drop other boolean columns from other tables (have +20 of other tables) - did not worked
5. Have tried to drop other data type columns - it worked (but not with boolean)

Any advices I could try next?

I have checked case sensitivity and everything matches but maybe I do not see something as it accours in all tables

Thank you in advance for your advises or pinpointing the reason

UPDATE:
In the same chainSet after dropping the `some_column` I modify VIEW table which had `some_column` variable

Comment: So you were able to rename the column? Maybe you need to specify `schemaName`? Like: `<dropColumn tableName="CE_SOME_TABLE" columnName="some_column2" schemaName="YOUR_SCHEMA"/>`

Comment: Thank you for your response but I found the answer recently, I will write it in the comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changeSet consisted of modifying the `SOME_TABLE` by dropping `some_column` out of it

Then in the same changeSet I had modiffied VIEW table which had old `some_column` value as it was not necessary anymore

The reason why I got exception was because when dropping column from table the view table was still holding it and was not letting it to drop

How I fixed it:

First altered view table by removing `some_column` variable

Then dropped `some_column` from `SOME_TABLE`